# MySQLWorkbench forward engineering error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I'm working on a model in MySql Workbench 8.0, when I click on forward engineering and try to generate the script of my model I get

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Compras_Personas`
    FOREIGN KEY (`persona_id`)
    R' at line 9
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `bd_inventario2018_2`.`compras`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bd_inventario2018_2`.`compras` (
          `nmcompra` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `persona_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `fecompra` DATE NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`nmcompra`, `persona_id`),
          INDEX `fk_Compras_Personas_idx` (`persona_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Compras_Personas`
            FOREIGN KEY (`persona_id`)
            REFERENCES `bd_inventario2018_2`.`personas` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Or when i try to syncronize the model I get

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE' at line 4
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `bd_inventario2018_2`.`productos` 
        ADD COLUMN `anchetas_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `psventa`,
        ADD COLUMN `productoscol` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL AFTER `anchetas_id`,
        ADD INDEX `fk_productos_Anchetas1_idx` (`anchetas_id` ASC) VISIBLE

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Someone knows what's happening? This is an automatic process, I'm not overwritting anything,

Thanks

Comment: VISIBLE / INVISIBLE option for INDEX constraints are not supported on MySQL 5.x, only on MySQL 8+. Just remove it and SQL script will execute.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is generating the script for MySQL 8 (which supports the new invisible indexes), which you likely do not have.

You need to specify the MySQL version you are using, either in `Model\Model Options\MySQL\Target MySQL Version` or, globally, in `Edit\Preferences\Modelling\MySQL\Target MySQL Version`.

Comment: Same issue for me.  I checked MAMP and changed the Workbench settings to match.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can go on the MySQL Workbench GUI, Edit->Preferences then Modeling->Mysql and change the default target MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, using version = 8.0.17.

The error originates when a relationship is formed if No action is selected in the  "Foreign Key Options" section. Ensure that the Skip in SQL generation is checked (When No action is selected).

[image]

This should solve the problem!

Comment: No, that's probably related to using MyISAM storage engine. You need to use InnoDb to enable fk constraints and/or the Foreign Key Options you used.