# How to I get MySQL Workbench to recognize MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When viewing the server status of MySQL Workbench, it states that the version used is "5.7.24 (MySQL Community Server(GLP))". When attempting to update this to a newer version, I found that according to the MySQL Installer, Workbench should already be using version 8.0:

[image: Screenshot of the Installer versions]

This in turn is giving me errors related to non-matching version numbers when attempting to use data exportation features of Workbench.  Am I missing something obvious? I am not sure why Workbench wont recognize/use the updated MySQL.

Comment: Instead of updating have you tried uninstalling the old one and then install 8.0

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you have/try to do. Workbench and the MySQL server are two different programs. You can use Workbench 8 to connect to a 5.7 server (which seems to be what you are currently doing). If you want to use server 8.0, you have to update the server, not (only) the workbench. If that's what you are trying to do, and if you get an error/problem with that, add information about this. If you want to keep using server 5.7, but workbench 8 scripts create errors (as the scripts are for 8.0), add these errors (or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859522)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question correctly, but it looks like you are trying to use MySQL Workbench 8.0.17 to export data from a different server (you didn't say what this is, but I assume it's a remote one). MySQL Workbench uses mysqldump to export data (dump it) and ships with that (using the latest available version at the time of release of MySQL Workbench).

Unfortunately, mysqldump versions are not backwards compatible (at least not intentionally), so when you use a 8.0.17 mysqldump version to dump a 5.6. server, it might come to problems. This is what MySQL Workbench warns about. In the preferences of MySQL Workbench is a setting that allows to specify a different mysqldump binary:

[image]

Use that to switch between mysqldump versions that match your server version for best results.

Comment: I understand that my question is a bit unclear, but I am just getting started with Workbench so there is still a lot that I don't understand.  When viewing my administration preferences, I am not sure what I should be seeing vs what my workbench displays.  My path to mysqldump tool is different than my export directory path, and the path to mysql tool has nothing at all.  Not sure if it should be this way.

Comment: If you don't specify an external tool then MySQLWorkbench uses the one it ships with. If you want a different one then download one of the other server packages (which contains the version of mysqldump for this server) and store that in a convenient location. Then point WB to it.